# pd replace but based on other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

i have this dataframe

```
data = {'col_1': ['together', 'married', 'single', 'together'],
'kids': [1, 0, 0, 0],
'teen': [1, 1, 0, 0]
}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df
```

| Column A | Kids | Teen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Together | 1 | 1 |
| Married | 0 | 1 |
| Single | 0 | 0 |
| Together | 0 | 0 |

I've been wondering, is it possible to replace 'together' with 'married' or 'single' based on many kid or teen which single dont have kids nor teen and married have kids or teen?

I've been trying to use apply function but still inexperience on using it

Comment: married may not have kids or teen

Comment: provide desired output by table

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest now that u mention it, after do some search turns out the value married without kids or teen comes up...

Answer (score 0):

If you make the assumption that having Kids or Teens necessarily makes the category "married", then you can use [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
m = df['col_1'].eq('together')
df.loc[m, 'col_1'] = np.where(df.loc[m, ['kids', 'teen']].sum(axis=1).gt(0),
                              'married', 'single')
```

If "married" and "single" are the only two option, you can also recompute all:

```
df['col_1'] = np.where(df[['kids', 'teen']].eq(1).any(axis=1),
                       'married', 'single')
```

Output:

```
     col_1  kids  teen
0  married     1     1
1  married     0     1
2   single     0     0
3   single     0     0
```